# How to make pgsql return the json array

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

everyone , I face some issue to convert the data into json object. There is a table called milestone with the following data:

```
id  name    parentId
a   test1   A
b   test2   B
c   test3   C
```

I want to convert the result into a json type in Postgres:

```
[{"id": "a", "name": "test1", "parentId": "A"}]
[{"id": "b", "name": "test2", "parentId": "B"}]
[{"id": "c", "name": "test3", "parentId": "C"}]
```

if there are anyone know how to handle , please let me know , thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You can get each row of the table as simple json object with `to_jsonb()`:

```
select to_jsonb(m)
from milestone m

                   to_jsonb                    
-----------------------------------------------
 {"id": "a", "name": "test1", "parentid": "A"}
 {"id": "b", "name": "test2", "parentid": "B"}
 {"id": "c", "name": "test3", "parentid": "C"}
(3 rows)
```

If you want to get a single element array for each row, use `jsonb_build_array()`:

```
select jsonb_build_array(to_jsonb(m))
from milestone m

                jsonb_build_array                
-------------------------------------------------
 [{"id": "a", "name": "test1", "parentid": "A"}]
 [{"id": "b", "name": "test2", "parentid": "B"}]
 [{"id": "c", "name": "test3", "parentid": "C"}]
(3 rows)
```

You can also get all rows as a json array with `jsonb_agg()`:

```
select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(m))
from milestone m

                                                                   jsonb_agg                                                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"id": "a", "name": "test1", "parentid": "A"}, {"id": "b", "name": "test2", "parentid": "B"}, {"id": "c", "name": "test3", "parentid": "C"}]
(1 row)
```

Read about [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ROW_TO_JSON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html)

From *Documentation* :

> Returns the row as a JSON object. Line feeds will be added between
>   level-1 elements if pretty_bool is true.

For the query :

```
select 
  row_to_json(tbl) 
from 
 (select * from tbl) as tbl;
```

You can check here in [*DEMO*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=414834befabdb7c9ab1836160186b49f)